# Можно ли перевести SQL-запрос в code-first linq-запрос для C# Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

Есть следующий SQL-запрос:

```
select o.ID
    , o.DigitalNumber
    , isnull(sum(m.Quantity * case when r.StatusID != 3 then r.Time else 0 end) / 60.0, 0) AllSumm
from O o
left join M m on o.ID = m.OID
left join R r on m.ID = r.MID
where o.StatusID = 1 and m.StatusID != 3
group by o.ID
    , o.DigitalNumber
order by o.ID desc;
```

Который далее через SqlConnection передаёт данные в C#:

```
var query = @"(код выше)";
using (var connection = ConnectionFactory.CreateDbConnection()) // SqlConnection
{
    var items = connection.Query<OwithAdds>(query);
    return items.ToList();
}
```

Хочу написать его версию на linq, чтобы эта версия смаппилась именно в sql-код выше (требуется высокая производительность). **Есть ли такая возможность?**

*Версии: Net Framework 4.5.2, Entity Framework 6.3.0*

---

Пробовал написать следующую версию, но она маппится в какой-то совсем уж монструозный многоуровневый sql-код (смотрел в Profiler), который работает очень долго (5s против 200ms):

```
return (from R in _rRepository.Table //IQueryable<R>
    where (r.M.StatusID != 3)
    group r by r.M.O
    into g
    where (g.Key.StatusID == 1)
    orderby g.Key.ID descending
    select new OwithAdds 
    {
        ID = g.Key.ID,
        DigitalNumber = g.Key.DigitalNumber,
        AllSumm = g.Sum(x => x.StatusID != 3 ? x.Time * x.M.Quantity : 0) / 60.0 ?? 0
    })
    .ToList();
```

Классы в C# (сущности БД им полностью соответствуют) выглядят следующим образом:

```
public class O
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long StatusID { get; set; }
    public string DigitalNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<M> Ms
    {
        get { return _ms ?? (_ms = new List<M>()); }
        protected set { _ms = value; }
    }
    private ICollection<M> _ms;    
}

public class M
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long StatusID { get; set; }
    public long? Quantity { get; set; }

    public long OID { get; set; }
    public virtual O O { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<R> Rs
    {
        get { return _rs ?? (_rs = new List<R>()); }
        protected set { _rs = value; }
    }
    private ICollection<R> _rs;    
}

public class R
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long StatusID { get; set; }
    public long? Time { get; set; }

    public long MID { get; set; }    
    public virtual M M { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *Хочу написать его версию на linq, чтобы эта версия смаппилась именно в sql-код выше* — это неверный подход, EF нужен как раз для того, чтобы не писать (да и вообще не думать о) SQL. К тому же конечный результат может меняться в разных версиях провайдера

Comment: Но да, ваш linq странен, почему вы идете как-то "наизнанку", а не начинаете с O?

Comment: Во WHERE есть условие `m.StatusID != 3`, которое преобразует `left join M m` в INNER JOIN. Либо замените тип связывания, либо переместите условие в ON (зависит от требуемой логики).

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, я в курсе, потому и задал вопрос. Изначально вообще была версия, где эти вычисления производились прям в C#, но она тоже работала в 10 раз медленнее. Поэтому я временно (надеюсь) вынес логику в базу как сумел, чтобы работало быстро. Сейчас всё работает по сути мгновенно, но пока есть время я бы хотел по возможности поправить. Версии фреймворков указаны, сервак: MS SQL Server 14.0.

Comment: Начните с чего-то вроде `os.Where(o => o.StatusID == 1).Select(o => new { o.ID, o.DigitalNumber, AllSumm = o.Ms.Where(m => m.StatusID != 3).SelectMany(m => m.Rs.Where(r => r.StatusID != 3), (m, r) => new { m.Quantity, r.Time }).Sum(a => a.Quantity * a.Time) / 60.0 ?? 0 }).ToList()`

Comment: Или даже т.к. `Q * T1 + Q * T2 + ... = Q * (T1 + T2 + ...)`, можно избавиться от `SelectMany`: `AllSumm = o.Ms.Where(m => m.StatusID != 3).Sum(m => m.Quantity * m.Rs.Where(r => r.StatusID != 3).Sum(r => r.Time)) / 60.0 ?? 0`

Comment: @AlMaslov, после того как вы перепишете запрос начиная с O, монстры должны будут уйти и тогда вас уже не будет интересовать какой там дословно формируется SQL. Ну а вообще такой linq у вас получается именно из-за того, что пытаетесь *перевести SQL в LINQ*, так не надо делать, это разные вещи. LINQ — это всё же работа с объектами и надо мыслить в терминах объектов, т. е. полагаясь на семантику